# Lacking the memory usage session in my diagnostic tools

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, diagnostic-tools

This is how it looks like on my screen.[image]

I have enabled it in *debug>options>debugging>general>enable diagnostic while debuggin*. But all I get is the screen above, while it should look like this

[image]

How can I fix it?I'm using visual studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected UX if you did not take any snapshots yet. Try to take snapshot and it will show in a table in Memory Usage tab. You can find more details [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/02/15/analyze-cpu-memory-while-debugging/).